# Why does $Ext(\mathbb{Z}_n,G)=G/nG$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In his book "Algebraic Topology", Hatcher introduces the functor $Ext$ and claims it satisfies:
$$
Ext(\mathbb{Z}_n,G)=G/nG
$$
His proof is as follows (irrelevant parts are trimmed):

> ...comes from dualizing the free resolution: $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{n}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow 0$$ to produce the exact sequence: [image]

I don't see how does dualizing the free-resolution produces the exact sequence.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exact sequence:
$$ \mathbb Z \overset{n}{\to} \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_n \to 0$$

Applying the (contravariant) functor $\text{Hom}( \_, G)$ to this exact sequence, we get another exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z_n, G) \to \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star) $$

[It is a standard fact in homological algebra that if $L\to M \to N \to  0$ is exact, then $ 0 \to \text{Hom}( N, G) \to \text{Hom}( M, G) \to \text{Hom}( L, G) $ is exact.]

---

The following is a free resolution of $\mathbb Z_n$:
$$ \dots \to 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb Z \overset{n}{\to} \mathbb Z $$

Applying the contravariant functor $\text{Hom}( \_, G)$ to this gives us a *chain complex*:

$$ \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \to 0 \to 0 \to \dots $$

I'll emphasise that this sequence we've just produced is *not* exact - it is merely a *chain complex*.

By definition, $\text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G)$ is the quotient
$$ \text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) = \frac{\text{Ker}[\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \to 0]}{\text{Im}[\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G)]}.$$

Clearly, $\text{Ker}[\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \to 0] = \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) $, so
$$ \text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) = \frac{\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G)}{\text{Im}[\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G)]}.$$

Thus the following is an exact sequence:
$$ \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \to \text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) \to 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star \star)$$

---

Combining $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$, we see that the following sequence is exact:
$$ 0 \to \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z_n, G) \to \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \to \text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) \to 0$$

This sequence is exact at $\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z_n, G)$ and at the first $\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) $ since $(\star)$ is exact.

This sequence is exact at the second $\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) $ and at $\text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) $ since $(\star\star)$ is exact.

---

**Edit:** I noticed that the title of your question is "Why does $\text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) = G / nG$?" If this is all your care about, then we don't need to do all this work to derive the exact sequence above. All we need to do is look at the formula:
$$ \text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) = \frac{\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G)}{\text{Im}[\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G) \overset{n}{\to} \text{Hom}( \mathbb Z, G)]}.$$

The numerator of the quotient is $G$ and the denominator of the quotient is $nG$, so $\text{Ext}(\mathbb Z, G) = G / nG$.

Comment: Thanks a million! Correct me if I'm wrong @Kenny - in the free resolution for $\mathbb{Z}_n$, I think the last term should be $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and the mapping should really be the $(mod \ n)$ and not multiply by n.

Comment: @NG_ When I wrote out the free resolution of $\mathbb Z_n$, I deliberately omitted the $\mathbb Z_n$ term and started with the $\mathbb Z$ term. I did this so that the $n$th term in my complex corresponds to $Ext^n$. I think it's quite common for people to use the phrase "free resolution"  to refer to the part of that long exact sequence up to but _not including_ the module that you're resolving.

Comment: Anyway, this is merely a matter of definition. It doesn't affect the answer to the question you posed.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I realised what caused the confusion - I omitted $\mathbb Z_n$ but I didn't omit $\text{Hom}( \mathbb Z_n, G) $ in the next line. That's been fixed. Apologies.